# Fast scraping of dynamic web page using Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, dynamic, timing

I've been testing grabbing data from a motor racing live timing page. It updates several times a second.
I've been using Selenium to grab by id the data I'm after.
But there are 20 drivers times about 11 stats.
This means that it takes about 3 seconds to grab this data before it starts again.
Is there a faster way?

```
driverList = []
drivernums = ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17',
              '18', '19', '20']
for d in range(1, 22):
    driverList.append(
        {"Pos": 0, "Name": '', "Lap": 0, "Gap": 0, "Interval": 0, "Pits": 0, 'Tyres': 0, 'S1': 0, 'S2': 0, 'S3': 0,
         'Laptime': 0})

while True:
    sessiontimeremaining = driver.find_element_by_id('stats_si_time')
    safetycar = driver.find_element_by_id('stats_si_safetycar')
    racelaps = driver.find_element_by_id('stats_si_laps')
    for d in drivernums:
        driverList[int(d)]['Pos'] = driver.find_element_by_id(f'i_{d}_pos').text
        driverList[int(d)]['Name'] = driver.find_element_by_id(f'i_{d}_nick').text[0:3].upper()
        driverList[int(d)]['Lap'] = driver.find_element_by_id(f'i_{d}_lap').text
        driverList[int(d)]['Gap'] = driver.find_element_by_id(f'i_{d}_gap').text
        driverList[int(d)]['Interval'] = driver.find_element_by_id(f'i_{d}_int').text[:-1]
        driverList[int(d)]['Pits'] = driver.find_element_by_id(f'i_{d}_pits').text
        driverList[int(d)]['Tyres'] = driver.find_element_by_id(f'i_{d}_tyres').text
        driverList[int(d)]['S1'] = driver.find_element_by_id(f'i_{d}_s1').text
        driverList[int(d)]['S2'] = driver.find_element_by_id(f'i_{d}_s2').text
        driverList[int(d)]['S3'] = driver.find_element_by_id(f'i_{d}_s3').text
        driverList[int(d)]['Laptime'] = driver.find_element_by_id(f'i_{d}_t').text
```

Comment: create multiple threads

Comment: Be carefull, faster will make you blacklisted from website :/

Comment: can you share the url? @Wazted since user uses selenium, I am not sure why he would get blacklisted (as long as he keeps selenium page live and does not reload it multiple times..., then multithread should do the trick).Depends if page is live or needs reloading(hence i ask url). For multithread, it has been made easier: https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html

Comment: https://f1.tfeed.net/2019/hockenheim       I'm not refreshing the page over and over - it does that itsellf.              I don't know how to do multiple threads.